# Do Indian passport holders need a transit visa at Frankfurt?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, frankfurt

I'm an Indian citizen travelling back to India. On the way, I have a layover time of 8 hours at Frankfurt International Airport. Do I need a transit visa? I have an Indian passport and Brazilian tourist visa.

Comment: What is your route of flight? Brazil->Frankfurt->India? Or are there more stops?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will Need a visa. If your baggage will be checked through, apply for an A-type Schengen visa. If you Need to collect and re-check it, apply for a C-type Schengen visa